# document expired same page form

Tags: php

on `request.php` i have a form, which also processes to the same page.  If the user is not signed in/up, a sign up form will be included on the processed `request.php`.

request.php

```
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //post variables
    //sign up form if not signed in
    } 

    //form
```

The sign up form is processed on `register.php`.  So `request.php->request.php(process)->register.php`.
If the user sign up is unsuccessful on `register.php` and presses the back button, i get `document expired`.  How do i solve this?  It should just show the page with the form.

Comment: Why not submit the result on the same page?

Comment: I am not sure I know what you're saying, but maybe this helps: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get - basically, control page flows when using post data. Perhaps you're expiring is related to form post duplicate warnings or something

Comment: That error is occurring because request.php is processing towards itself, and THEN it redirects to register. If the user presses the back button, they will be redirected to the second request.php that was called by the first. Since the first is no longer running, the document is expired. Why not just redirect to register.php FROM request.php instead of doing it twice? So just do `request.php->register.php`.

Comment: Show us what is inside the request.php and register.php page

Answer (score 0):

Just put a `header('location:request.php');` if user registration fails in `request.php`

And, PHP will itself, do the job of taking you back.

Maybe something like this..

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

  if(isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username'])) {

   // authentication code goes here
   } // if username is empty, then.. `header('location:request.php')` // this means go back.


} else { echo " enter user id, to log in";}
```